# How to make SingleChoiceItem on AlertDialog looks more compact?

Tags: android, styles, customization, android-alertdialog

The default AlertDialog has bigger textSize and bigger padding.

I can control the textSize by using Style like this

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme );
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cw);
```

Then

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Now how to adjust the vertical spacing / padding of the AlertDialog? The style below does not affect anything. Or at least can we adjust the size of the RadioButton too?

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

The line is I want to use default AlertDialog with Style customization. I dont want creating custom Adapter just to make custom view for the AlertDialog.

Thanks

Comment: I've found a similar issue in trying to style the checkboxes of an AlertDialog.  Not all items in the default are available to be styled. You have to go ahead and make the full custom dialog, including a layout, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no option than build full custom Dialog using Adapter then. Thanks anyway.